# SSMS Results to Separate tab ignored on SELECT TOP 1000 Rows Right Click Menu

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have [configured SSMS to display results to a separate pane](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/display-query-editor-and-results-in-seperate-tab-in-ssms/) which works fine when I create new queries using the "New Query" button.

However, when I right click on a table and click `SELECT TOP 1000 Rows` it displays the result in the "old style" window with code at the top and results at the bottom.

Is there something I have missed or is this a feature?

I am using Management Studio 17.9.1

Comment: Don’t use the SELECT TOP 1000 rows feature then. With IntelliSense you could type out the command just as quickly and get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: SMSS 16.something on my machine does the same thing, FWIW